# Does ffmpeg version 0.5 configured on linux support encoding using Theora codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, theora

I have configured, compiled a ffmpeg source code version 0.5 with versions as below:

FFmpeg version 0.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: --enable-memalign-hack libavutil 49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0 libavcodec 52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0 libavformat 52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0 libavdevice 52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0 on a linux host.

When i try to encode a raw yuv video using this version using theora codec by giving options as :

ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 352x288 -r 30 -i foreman_352_x280_420.yuv -an -vcodec libtheora theora1.ogg

It gives an error: Unknown encoder 'libtheora'

But when i use the same command in a ffmpeg windows executable ( whose version is FFmpeg version SVN-r12665) it encoded to a theora video properly.

1) Doesnt ffmpeg version 0.5 on linux support theora encoder?

2)Which version for linux setup,would support theora encoding?

Thanks,

-AD.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to install (compile) `libtheora` for your linux distribution from http://www.theora.org/downloads/ . It might be that the windows distribution you used has it bundled, while the linux one does not.

Comment: Yep. On my Mac, running `ffmpeg` comes up with `--enable-libtheora` in the configure options, among other things.